# How do erase data on text file?

Tags: android, text-files, delete-file

I have this code :

```
public void makeFile(String sFileName, int gene_ration)
    {
        try
        {
            //deleteFile("genetic_algorithm.txt"); 
            if (!myfile.exists()) {
                myfile.mkdirs();
            }

            File gpxfile = new File(myfile, sFileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile, true);
            writer.append("Generation " + gene_ration + "\r\n");
            for(chromosomesNumber = 0; chromosomesNumber < indexOfChromosomes ; chromosomesNumber++)
            {   writer.append(chromosomesNumber + ". " );
                writer.append(population[chromosomesNumber] + " ");
                writer.append("Nilai fitness : " + population[chromosomesNumber].fitness + "\r\n");
            }
            writer.append("\r\n");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
             String importError = e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I want to erase data on textfile every time I compile it and before add data to textfile. How can I do that? any idea?

Comment: Using `write` instead of `append` for the firs operation doesn't do the job?

Answer (score 0):

There's a File.delete() method

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()

Comment: myfile.delete() nothing happen

Comment: Check if delete returns true. If false is returned that means the file could not be deleted (probably it doesn't exist or the path incorrect)